# How can I kill a parent from a child process using multiprocessing in Python and Windows?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, kill-process

I want to end my script when one of the child processes reaches a specific point. Let's suppose I have the following code:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys


def another_child_process (my_queue):
    time.sleep(3)
    my_queue.put("finish")

def my_process(my_queue):
    while True:
        if my_queue.empty() is False:
            my_queue.get()
            print("Killing the program...")
            ### THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO KILL MAIN PROCESS AND EXIT
            sys.exit(0) 


def main():

    ## PARENT PROCESS WHICH I WANT TO KILL FROM THE CHILD

    my_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    child_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_process, args=(my_queue,))
    another_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=another_child_process, args=(my_queue,))

    child_process.start()
    another_process.start()

    while True:
        pass ## I want to end the program in the child process

       
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I have read something about using signals, but they are for Linux mainly and I don't know well how to use them in Windows. I'm a begginer in Python in reality. How could I end the script completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you read the documentation carefully, you will see that calling method `is_empty` on a `multiprocessing.Queue` is not reliable and should not be used. Moreover, you have a *race condition*. That is, if `my_process` runs before `another_child_process` (and assuming `is_empty` was reliable), it would find the queue empty and terminate prematurely because `another_child_process` has not yet had the chance to put any items on the queue. So what you should be doing is having `another_child_process` put whatever messages it wants on the queue but then put an additional *sentinel* item whose purpose is to signal that there are no more items that will be put on the queue. Thus the *sentinel* serves as a quasi end-of-file indicator. You can use any distinct object to serve as the *sentinel* as long as it cannot be taken for a "real" data item. In this case we will use `None` as the sentinel.

But the actual example you have coded is not a realistic example demonstrating why you would need some special mechanism to terminate the main process and exit since once `another_process` has put its items on the queue, it returns and thus the process terminates and once `my_process` detects that it has retrieved all the items from the queue and that there will be no more, it returns and thus its process terminates. Thus, all the main process has to do is issue a calls to `join` on the two subprocesses and wait for them to complete and then exit:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

def another_child_process (my_queue):
    time.sleep(3)
    my_queue.put("finish")
    my_queue.put(None)

def my_process(my_queue):
    while True:
        item = my_queue.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        print('Item:', item)


def main():

    ## PARENT PROCESS WHICH I WANT TO KILL FROM THE CHILD

    my_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    child_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_process, args=(my_queue,))
    another_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=another_child_process, args=(my_queue,))

    child_process.start()
    another_process.start()

    child_process.join()
    another_process.join()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Item: finish
```

Here is perhaps a better example. `another_child_process` gets data in some fashion (for demo purposes we have a generator function, `get_data`). If no abnormal situation occurs, it puts all the data on the queue for `my_process` to get followed by the `None` sentinel item so `my_process` knows that there is no more data forthcoming and it can terminate. But let's suppose that there is the possibility of `get_data` producing a special, abnormal data item, the string 'finish' for demo purposes. In that case `another_child_process` will terminate immediately. At that point, however, there be many items on the queue that `my_process` has not retrieved and processed yet. We would like to force the termination of `my_process` immediately so that the main process can immediately `join` the subprocesses and terminate.

To accomplish this we pass an event to a daemon thread started by the main process, which waits for the event to be set. If the event is set by `another_child_process`, to which we have also passed the event, the thread will immediately terminate the `my_process` process:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

def get_data():
    for item in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'finish', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']:
        yield item

def another_child_process(my_queue, exit_event):
    for item in get_data():
        if item == 'finish':
            # Abnormal condition where we must exit imemediately.
            # Immediately signal main process terminate:
            exit_event.set()
            # And we terminate:
            return
        my_queue.put(item)
    # Normal situation where we just continue
    # Put in sentinel signifying no more data:
    my_queue.put(None)

def my_process(my_queue):
    while True:
        item = my_queue.get()
        if item is None: # Sentinel?
            # No more data:
            break
        print("Got: ", repr(item))
    print('my_process terminating normally.')

def main():
    import threading

    def wait_for_quit(exit_event):
        nonlocal child_process

        exit_event.wait()
        child_process.terminate()
        print("Exiting because event was set.")

    exit_event = multiprocessing.Event()

    # Start daemon thread that will wait for the quit_event
    threading.Thread(target=wait_for_quit, args=(exit_event,), daemon=True).start()

    my_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    child_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_process, args=(my_queue,))
    another_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=another_child_process, args=(my_queue, exit_event))

    child_process.start()
    another_process.start()

    # Wait for processes to end:
    child_process.join()
    another_process.join()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Got:  'a'
Exiting because event was set.
```

If you remove the `finish` message from the data returned by `get_data`, then  all processes will complete normally and what gets printed will be:

```None
Got:  'a'
Got:  'b'
Got:  'c'
Got:  'd'
Got:  'e'
Got:  'f'
Got:  'g'
my_process terminating normally.
```